# Outlook 2007 conversation showing incorrectly

Tags: outlook-2007

In Office 2007, conversations are very strange and out of order when a message is view in it's own window.

For example, 3 messages would display as -

```
Message 2 header
<break>
Message 1 header
Message 1
Message 2
Message 3
```

This is very wierd, and all sorts of confusing, as you have to scroll to the bottom of the message to find the reply that has been sent.

The expected format should be -

```
Message 3
<break>
Message 2 header
Message 2
<break>
Message 1 header
Message 1
```

Does anybody know of a setting to change this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, this turned out to be an error in the set up our our disclaimer software (Mail Exclaimer).